# Making read-Only rows using jQuery DataTable Grid

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using  [Jquery DataTable Grid](http://www.datatables.net).
Here I am Making cells edit as in :
 [this Example](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/events.html).

Now If the column 'Engine version' has value "420", Then i want to make the whole row read-only.

Please help me out.

Edit:

```
  var oTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
          oTable=  $('#example').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "GetWebAlerts.aspx",
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aLengthMenu": [ 10,25,50,100,200,500 ],
                 "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                   if (oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered) {
                    if (oSettings.aoColumns[1].bVisible == true) {
                        for (var i = 0, iLen = oSettings.aiDisplay.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                            $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[oSettings.aiDisplay[i]].nTr).html(i + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
                "aaSorting": [[3, "desc"]],
                aoColumns: [
                 { "bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
               {"sClass" : "left", "bVisible": true, "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1] },
                 { "bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [2] },
                 { "bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [3] },
                 { "bVisible": true, "sType": "num-html","bSortable": false,
                    "fnRender": function (oData, sVal) {

                        if (sVal.indexOf("OVERSPEED") >= 0) {                            
                       return "<span title='Overspeed = " +  oData.aData[8] + " KM/H'>" + sVal + "(" + oData.aData[8] +" KM/H)</span>";                                                        
                       }
                        else if (sVal.indexOf("IDLING") >= 0) {
                            return "<span title='Idling from = " + oData.aData[8].split(";")[0] + " For "+ oData.aData[8].split(";")[1] + " Mins'>" + sVal + "("+ oData.aData[8].split(";")[1]+  " Mins)</span>";
                            }
                         else if(sVal.indexOf("Geofence In") >= 0)
                         {
                            return "<span>" + oData.aData[8] + "- IN</span>";
                         }
                          else if(sVal.indexOf("Geofence out") >= 0)
                         {
                            return "<span>" + oData.aData[8] + "- OUT</span>";
                         }
                        else { 

                        return sVal;                              
                         }
                    }, "aTargets": [4], "asSorting": ["desc", "asc"] },

               { "bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [5] },
                 { "bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [6] },
                   { "bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [7] }

                     ]

                 }).makeEditable({
                                    sUpdateURL: "UpdateWebData.aspx?i=0",
                                    "aoColumns": [
                                         null,
                                           null,
                                           null,
                                           null,

                                           {
                                             indicator: 'Saving reason...',
                                             tooltip: 'Click to select reason',
                                             loadtext: 'loading...',
                                             type: 'select',
                                             onblur: 'submit',
                                             data: "{'1':'Accident','2':'Battery Taken Out','3':'In Workshop','4':'Not In Operation','5':'Signal Lost','6':'Other'}"                                                

                                           },


                                           {

                                           },
                                            null
                                     ],
                                       sDeleteURL: "UpdateWebData.aspx?i=1",
                                       oDeleteRowButtonOptions: {   label: "Remove", 
                                                icons: {primary:'ui-icon-trash'}
                                    },

                                });
                           });
```

This is my code.. I want to make readonly if the 5th number Json data from my page GetWebAlerts.aspx is "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out looking at your code I'll try to explain how I would go about doing this.

In the JS where they enter the value, check if the input is engine version, and the value is 420.
If it is, add a class to that row called 420row.

Then in the function where it binds the on click to change to input, change the selector to add `:not('.420row')`.

Again, if you post your code, or better yet make a jsfiddle, then I'll be able to help you out better.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to make row Non editable..... by adding onclick event to that perticular row and add condition on what bases you want to make Non editable. See the below code for example:

```
$('#employee tbody tr')
    .live('click', function() {
        var nTds = $('td', this);
        var designation = $(nTds[4]).text();
            if (designation == "****") {
             alert('Employee designation is **** so cannot update now');
            }
    });
```